# Pass local values to email template use Express-mailer

Tags: node.js, email, express

I want to send a thank you email after user sign up but i don't know how to pass username to my email template. I have the following code:

```
app.mailer.send('email', {
  to: 'newuser@gmail.com', // REQUIRED. This can be a comma delimited string just like a normal email to field. 
  subject: 'Test Email', // REQUIRED.
  user: req.body.user, // All additional properties are also passed to the template as local variables.
}, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
    console.log(err);
    res.send('There was an error sending the email');
    return;
  }
  res.send('Email Sent');
});
```

email template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{subject}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    Thank you {{user}}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass properties to the request.

`{
to: 'newuser@gmail.com', // REQUIRED. This can be a comma delimited string just like a normal email to field. 
  subject: 'Test Email', // REQUIRED.
  username: req.body.username,
  myVar: 'username'
}`

The variable `myVar` is passed as local variable to the template

Comment: I guess the OP needs ti know how the variable sent is handled in the template.